# How to assign [WeatherModel]() to a JSON type in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I was building a model for my json object. And I did it.
Now I have to declare a variable for it in ViewController and assign it to my json object. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is how I parse json from a file and declare a var:

```
 var weatherData = [WeatherModel]()

 func getJSONData(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "weather", ofType: "json") {
        if let data = try? String(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath)) {
            let json = JSON(parseJSON: data)

            // I must assign json to weatherData here

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completed()
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("file not found")
    }
}
```

Here is my model jus in case:

```
struct WeatherModel: Codable {
  let list: [List]
  let city: City
}

struct City: Codable {
  let name: String
}

struct List: Codable {
  let main: Main
  let weather: [Weather]
  let dtTxt: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case main, weather
    case dtTxt = "dt_txt"
  }
}

 struct Main: Codable {
    let temp: Double
 }

 struct Weather: Codable {
    let main, description: String
 }
```

EDIT: Here's weather.json

```
     {
       "list": [
        {
           "main": {
               "temp": 277.12
            },
        "weather": [{
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "scattered clouds"
        }],
        "dt_txt": "2018-06-05 15:00:00"
    }
],
"city": {
    "name": "Bishkek"
   }
  }
```

Note: if there is any error in my code above, glad to hear a solution.

Comment: Where's your use of `JSONDecoder`?

Comment: Show us what your `weather.json` contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
let json = JSON(parseJSON: data)
```

You should be making use of `JSONDecoder`

```
let weatherData = try JSONDecoder().decode([WeatherModel].self,
                                           from:data)
```

---

In Example:

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "weather", ofType: "json") {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath))

        weatherData = try JSONDecoder().decode([WeatherModel].self,
                                               from:data)
        print(weatherData)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: is it SwiftyJSON? Because I need to make it using SwiftyJSON.

Comment: @IslamNurdinUulu Why needlessly use a 3rd party library?

Comment: @IslamNurdinUulu No, it is not `SwiftyJSON`. If you want to use a model then `SwiftyJSON` is not required. Not here at least.

Comment: @IslamNurdinUulu Also, just to be sure, add the contents of `weather.json` to your question.

Comment: @staticVoidMan it gives me this error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data'"

Comment: @rmaddy please take a look

Comment: @IslamNurdinUulu Because `let data = try? String()` gives `String`. Wait, will update answer

Comment: @staticVoidMan sure

Comment: @IslamNurdinUulu `data` should be of type `Data` not `String`. So basically `let data = try? String(...` should have been `let data = try? Data(...`. Anyways, updated answer

Comment: @staticVoidMan THANKS a lot! However, when I just ran it, it gives me this - "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." What format should data be?

Comment: @rmaddy Please take a look at last comment :)

Comment: @IslamNurdinUulu Maybe `WeatherModel.self` should be `[WeatherModel].self`. Which is why I asked for the `weather.json`. Check that. Will update answer once you confirm

Comment: @staticVoidMan yeah, I did that earlier. But even with [WeatherModel].self it gives the error I mentioned above.

Comment: @staticVoidMan it works! update the answer, I will confirm it.

Comment: @IslamNurdinUulu Awesome! Well... your models were right but you just needed `JSONDecoder`. Now you may set that to `self.weatherData` for use in your `ViewController` going forward.